# Vue - Correct way to make vuex store available to a programmatically created component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a .vue component, `Sectors`, which I want to add to a container called "desktop_sectors" when on a desktop

```
<v-flex sm12 md12 ma-2 ref="desktop_sectors">
```

or add to "mobile" if on a mobile

```
v-flex sm12 ma-2 ref="mobile">
```

So (as far as I know) I need to create the `Sectors` component programmatically, because I don't want it created two times, like below

```
<!-- desktop -->
<v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height hidden-sm-and-down>
  </v-flex>  
   <v-flex sm12 md12 ma-2 ref="desktop">
  </v-flex>               
</v-layout>  

<!-- mobile -->
<v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height hidden-md-and-up pa-t>
  <v-flex sm12 ma-2 ref="mobile">
    <Sectors/>
  </v-flex>                              
</v-layout>
```

so, I create it once, programmatically

```
  var componentClass = Vue.extend(Sectors)
  var instance = new componentClass(123)
  instance.store(this.$store)
  instance.$mount()
  console.log(instance)
  this.$refs.mobile.appendChild(instance.$el)
  this.$refs.desktop.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

Right now, I just have a method inside Sectors called `store` which I send the store instance to, but I was hoping that there was a better/correct way to make the store available to Sectors, perhaps using the `created()` method or `mounted()`

**Additional info**
I'm adding the component programmatically because in fact, I have multiple components in addition to `Sectors`, that all subscribe to some mutations in the store, and if I create the same components multiple times, the API calls that get triggered are double of what is necessary

Comment: You can passe the store object to your new component like:

      var instance = new componentClass({store: this.$store})

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256820/1308363

Answer (score 1):

I like to make the store available to all my components like so:

```
import storeConfig from './store'
Vue.prototype.$store = Vue.$store = storeConfig
```

You can access it inside your components like so:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    testStore(){
      console.log(this.$store)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - please explain what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

For Vue3 you can import store from where its defined and [use](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#using-a-plugin) it like so:

```js
    import <your component> from '<somewhere>';
    import { createApp } from 'vue';
    import { store } from '@/main.js';
    
    ...
    
    createApp(<your component>).use(store).mount("some selector");
```