# Mount component dynamically into DOM in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dynamic

I want to create a text highlighting feature in my app. Here is the idea: I am receiving a piece of HTML from an API endpoint and want to relace **some** elements with fully working Vue components.

I could achieve it with the help of also [this](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/) article and came up with the following essential lines:

```
// node is here the current HTML node from API
const textHighlight = new TextHighlightClass({ propsData: { text: node.innerText } });
textHighlight.$mount(document.getElementById(node.id));
```

The HTML itself was previously injected into a template element like this:

```
<div v-html="contentFromApi"></div>
```

The problem is apparently if you `$mount` the component instance it will not exist as part of the app hierarchy but on it's own.
I'm using a Vuex store to handle the logic so I would like to dispatch an action inside of the `TextHighlight` component. Trying to access `this.$store` is not possible as the store is unknown to `TextHighlight`. A solution for this I could find [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256820/1959760) doing like this:

```
const textHighlight = new TextHighlightClass({ store, propsData: { text: node.innerText } });
```

But this seems to be a workaround while the component itself is still **outside** of the main application.
Is there a better way to attach a component dynamically (programmatically) to the hierarchy?

There is also the way of using the [render function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) but I'm not sure how to use it in my case.